# ADB push throws "Device not found" error even though it can find device

Tags: android, ubuntu, adb

So I plug in my Samsung S3 into USB port. Ubuntu 13.10 recognizes it and everything is fine. 
I can deploy applications from android studio normally and when I run `adb devices` it shows me:

```
List of devices attached

4df1396551934f17    device
```

So everything is fine. Now when I call `adb shell` it starts also normally, after that I do `run-as com.myapp.something` and now that should give me permission to copy database from app to my computer.

I do `adb push /databases ~/` and it should copy databases folder to my home directory but it throws me `device not found` error which is strange to me because everything works until that point.

Comment: Have you tried `push`ing to a full path on your device, instead of just `~/`?

Comment: Also try with the -d flag: `adb -d push`

Comment: I tried adding full path, I tried adding -d flag but it didn't work.
I have a question, when I run "adb shell" and enter it, what should it write out?
When I run "adb devices" in linux terminal, it gives me that my mobile phone is connected, but from withing adb shell it tells me no phones are connected..

Comment: `adb shell` should throw you into a command line on the device itself, so if *that's* broken, there's something else going on. Does `adb devices` return anything if your device is unplugged? And what about an unplug/machine reboot/device reboot/try again? Most of my `adb`-related issues were just problems with USB or something stupid.

Comment: after I unplug my phone it returns nothing.. I will try to restart my machine now